# Menu icon size when migrating to AndroidX

Tags: java, android, androidx

We've recently updated our app to Android X as required by going to Refactor > Migrate to Android X in Android Studio. Most things seem to be working perfectly, but we've having an issue with image sizes - both in menus and in buttons.

For example:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu);
displayPhotos = menu.getItem(0);
displayPhotos.setIcon(
    Util.resize(
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable( getResources() , R.drawable.bb_photos_off, null)
        ,this,22,22
    )
);
```

With the resize function defined being as follows:

```
public static Drawable resize(Drawable image,Context c, int width, int height) {
    int iconWidth = (int)  TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, width, c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int iconHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, iconWidth,iconHeight, false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(c.getResources(),bitmapResized);
}
```

The resize function should create an image the correct size for the pixel density of the phone, to avoid us preparing multiple sizes of images.

Before the Migration, on an emulator running API 28, the images look perfect. Afterwards, they appear about twice the size.

Is there anything we've missed in the Android X Migration that could cause this issue?